# no such file or directory, chmod '/app/node_modules/@nuxt/telemetry/bin/nuxt-telemetry.js' Problem

Tags: nuxt.js, gtag.js

So im working on a project and i installed vue-gtag package via npm
after i did that i couldnt get my docker container up and even when i try to serve the up its still pop up this error message

[image]

'no such file or directory, chmod '/app/node_modules/@nuxt/telemetry/bin/nuxt-telemetry.js'

I am using
[image]

I've already tried reinstalling node and npm

Comment: Various things here, what is the warning over `@nuxtjs/gtm` etc in your VScode. Are you sure your node_modules are properly installed here? What version of Node are you using? What if you try out of Docker?

Comment: so... to explain i even went to another project at the folder and tried to run it (i didnt change or did anything on that project) an i realised that none of my projects run now. as they all woth the same problem as above
if i run my project with npm run dev and add the NUXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED=1  then the projects run fine... its like i need to disable them globally

Comment: Pretty sure that got nothing related to telemetry. Got a public github repo?